# How does defeating every Minecraft boss affect the game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How does defeating every Minecraft boss affect the game? Does it give you a special item or achievement or some diamonds or something like that?

Comment: I believe killing the Ender Dragon and the Wither do unlock an achievement in the achievements page. I havent played really since 1.12 so Im not sure if new bosses have been added. Killing the Ender Dragon also unlocks the End world where you can find shulker boxes and eltrya which can be seen as the special item. Plus killing the Wither gives you some star object thing (dont remember name) that can be used to create a beacon. Finally I think both give a bounty of xp.

Comment: @KyleRone It's called a "nether star".

Answer (score 9):

### The [Wither](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither)

- 50 experience
- 1 [nether star](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Star)

  - Can be used to craft a [beacon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon) with 5 glass and 3 obsidian

    - Can provide speed, haste, resistance, jump boost, strength, and/or regeneration to players nearby

### The [Ender Dragon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon)

- 12,000 experience if it was the first time you killed it, otherwise 500 experience.
- If you killed it for the first time, a [dragon egg](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg) generates above the exit portal.

  - The rarest item in the game as you can only legitimately gain 1 per world
- The [exit portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Exit_portal) (the bedrock structure in the centre) activates

  - Allows you to return to the Overworld
- An [end gateway](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_gateway) generates floating within 75–100 blocks of the exit portal (up to 20 times)

  - Enables you to access the [outer islands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End#Outer_islands)

    - [End cities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city) and [end ships](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city#End_Ship)

      - [Loot](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city#Loot)
      - 1 [elytra](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Elytra), which can be used to fly
      - 1 [dragon head](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head)
    - [Chorus trees](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chorus_tree)

      - [Chorus fruit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chorus_Fruit)

        - Can be eaten

          - Restores 4 (2 drumsticks) hunger
          - Get teleported to a random location within 8 blocks on all axes
        - Can be smelted into [popped chorus fruit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Popped_Chorus_Fruit)

          - Can be crafted into [end rods](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Rod) with 1 blaze rod, which provide a light level of 14
          - Can be crafted into [pupur blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Purpur_Block), which can be crafted into pillars, slabs, and stairs